# http request to get youtube comments

Tags: php, web, screen-scraping

I want to scrape the comments from video

I mimic the request found in the chrome console but I always get 403 in response code

Below is my code.

```
$ex = RestClient::get('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5w77nD7mdAA');


$html = $ex->getResponse();

$pre  = preg_match('/XSRF_TOKEN\': \"(.*)\"+/',$html,$matches);



 $url = 'https://www.youtube.com/comment_ajax?action_load_comments=1&order_by_time=true&filter=FWjnsL2kExY&order_menu=true';
  $ex = RestClient::post($url,array(
  'video_id'=>'5w77nD7mdAA',
  'session_token'=>$matches[1]
  ));
```

Comment: don't scrape youtube. use the api.